# DBvisualizer 9.1.12 errors on semicolon in comments

Tags: mysql, sql, comments, dbvisualizer

I recently upgraded my DBvisualizer from several versions back, to the most recent version (9.1.12), and I am getting errors on my code with reference to comment lines and semicolons in comments.

For instance, against a mysql DB:

select * from orders --test

results in:

Code: 1064 SQL State: 42000 --- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--test' at line 1

but if I put a space after -- then it executes correctly.

Also:

select * from orders 
/* test
test
--test;
*/

results in:

Code: 1064 SQL State: 42000 --- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*/' at line 1

but if I remove the semicolon from the above code the query executes correctly.

Neither of these conditions were cause for failure in previous version. I have checked the tool properties for comments and do not find that "-- " is present anywhere, and the settings regarding ";" say that it will be ignored in single line comments and block comments, which is apparently not the case.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this open the **SQL Commander** menu and make sure **Strip Comments when Execution** is checked before executing.

Regards

Roger